# send rendered GridView in an email

Tags: asp.net, email

I have a GridView whose HTML I need to put into an email.

How can this be done?

Comment: do accepte answer if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

use an HTMLtext writer to render the gridview control.You will get an HTML output as string.use this as your message body.

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you can do for this

1) take screen shot of the current page by using any utility and send in mail

2) you can export grid as excel and than sent it in mail.

Export grid to Excel
    http://geekswithblogs.net/azamsharp/archive/2005/12/21/63843.aspx

Comment: can you please tell me how to export grid as excel

Comment: @satya - check the updated answer I pasted link in that for export grid to excel or you can also search on google you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a stringbuilder to create a HTML table to resample your gridview like so:

```
var output = new StringBuilder("<table cellpadding='5' style='border: solid 1px black;'>");
foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
{
    output.Append("<tr>");
    output.Append("<td>" + Title + "</td>");
    output.Append("<td>" + Price + "</td>");
    output.Append("<td>" + Quantity + "</td>");
    output.Append("</tr>");

}
output.Append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be concerned about the GridView control. Take the data that is being displayed in the control, format it in what ever manner you want and pass it as your message body.

I would treat the logic to display Grid in my application and generating grid for message body as two separate functionality. What will be common in between the two, is the source of data. For formatting of data(generating the Grid), you can use the HTMLTextWriter class(as mentioned by others) and format the data in what ever way you want.